# Google Map event bounds_changed triggered multiple times when dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I have a google map with markers. I want my markers to be refreshed when the map is moved/zoomed...

Google recommend to use the event `bounds_changed` for that, but when I move the map, **the event is triggered for each pixel that I move the map**. I want the map to be refreshed only when the user stopped moving the map, i.e. when he released the mouse button after dragging.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It turns out it was a reported bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1371.

The Google team recommend to use the event "idle". For example :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
});
```

Comment: How can I set to trigger a custom mapupdate function after 2 seconds passed from starting the idle state?

Comment: i had the same issue with react while using this event handler  also...

Answer (score 13):

While the selected answer is best for most circumstances.  If you want to control the delay yourself, you can simply use something like;

```
 var mapupdater;

 {....}

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", mapSettleTime); 


 function mapSettleTime() {
     clearTimeout(mapupdater);
     mapupdater=setTimeout(getMapMarkers,500);
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

Add a timeout, that runs your code 500ms after the event fires, each time the event fires clear the timeout and create a new one.

```html
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
    var timer;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            // here goes an ajax call
        }, 500);
    }
}()));
```

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer. It's doing the same thing, but easier.

Answer (score 7):

You should check how a debounce function works. A nice [article by Taylor Case](https://medium.com/@TCAS3/debounce-deep-dive-javascript-es6-e6f8d983b7a1) define it as follows:

> This function is built in order to limit the amount of times a
>   function is called — scroll events, mousemove events, and keypress
>   events are all great examples of events that we might want to capture,
>   but can be quite taxing if we capture them every single time they
>   fire.

So you define the function somewhere in your code:

```
function debounce(fn, time) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const args = arguments;
    const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, args);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
  }
}
```

Then you just use that function when adding your listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, 'bounds_changed', debounce(() => { /* Do something here */ }, 250));
```

It seems that 250 ms is a good frequency to use here.

Answer (score 2):

try using both zoom_changed and dragend

Comment: it will definitely work perfect on zoomchange and dragend, but id doesn't work when we move map using pan control.

Comment: Be careful if you do this... you'll miss users that pan the map via keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet that will remove all redundant 'bound_changed' call's:

```
var timeout;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
window.clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    //do stuff on event
    }, 500);
}); //time in ms, that will reset if next 'bounds_changed' call is send, otherwise code will be executed after that time is up
```