# idle event on Google-maps with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, google-maps

I set a google map in my site, and I want to reload the markers whenever the map's bounds changes (by drag or zoom).

I was using jQuery to add the map and clear the markers at first:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap();
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
```

and then, add the markers with:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': position, 'bounds': true });
```

My question: 
How can I "catch" the event of moving the map? I already read that there is the idle event, and [I saw an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338490/google-map-event-bounds-changed-triggered-multiple-times-when-dragging):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
});
```

but anything that I put instead of the "map" variable doesn't work...
I also tried:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Danny

Comment: Could you please include some information regarding which gmap jquery plug-in you are using; there appear to be a couple out there.

Answer (score 6):

For others having this issue:

You can get the map object/variable like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap();
var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
```

Once you have the map object, you can attach event listeners to it:

```
$(map).addEventListener('idle', function() {
    console.log('Map is now idle');
    console.log(map.getCenter());
});
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

inside your defined function you can do whatever you want. It is called always the map bounds change. For example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
 var bounds = map.getBounds();
 var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
 var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
 alert("minimum lat of current map view: " + sw.lat());
});
```

"map" should be the google map you created before.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions );
```

Cheers!
Thomas

Comment: This is not a solution, OP can get to bind the event because he doesn't have the `map` variable, because he used the `jquery.gmap` plugin.