# when user get zoomed in some area on map, display specific data from different function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

when user get close to some area on map, display specific data from one other function? I am calculating average of each area estate prices in computed functions. it's below. you can see the average function on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw2r89q4/1/)...

Already displaying averages but, what I need to do here, when user get zoomed in that region/city then display that areas average... The original code with map down below...

For example, how to sets bounds and connect those bounds to average function??? Thank you for helping.!

### code updated!

```js
data() {
        return {
            avg:"",
            map: {},
            mapName: "map",
            estates: [],
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates =  response.data
        });

        this.initMap();

    },
    methods: {

       initMap: function(){
            var mapOptions =
                {
                    zoom : 6,
                    center : {
                        lat:34.652500,
                        lng:135.506302
                    }
                };

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                console.log("bound changed alert");
            });
        },


        avgArray: function (region) {
             const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a,c) => (a += c),0);
             const avg = arr => sum(arr) / arr.length;

             return avg(region);
        },


    },
    computed: {
 
        groupedPricesByRegion () {
         return this.estates.reduce((acc, obj) => {
            var key = obj.region;

            if (!acc[key]) {
              acc[key] = [];
            }

                acc[key].push(obj.m2_price);

                return acc;
            }, {});
        },

        averagesByRegion () {
         let arr = [];
            Object.entries(this.groupedPricesByRegion)
                .forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    arr.push({ [key]: Math.round(this.avgArray(value)) });
            });

            return arr;
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is specific to vue, its more about google-maps.

You can listen to the `bounds_changed` event on the map object: [bounds_changed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.bounds_changed)

And then get the boundaries of your current view

Have a look at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983234/get-current-latlng-bounds) which should help you out.

If you are using vuejs, you an look at this library [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/) which should help you out.

P.S make sure to debounce the function you call on `bounds_changed` or you may make a lot of unnecessary calls to your generating-averages function